# How to show the busy indicator while loading the page, and we need to hide the busy indicator after page load completed in primefaces,javascript

Tags: javascript, primefaces

The Menu has Listpages, and detail pages. While Clicking the Menu item we need show busy indicator, and hide the indicator while loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `p:ajaxStatus` for it. Add following code in template and defined image will be displayed during ajax actions:

```
    <p:ajaxStatus id="ajaxstatus" style="float: right;">
        <f:facet name="start">
            <h:graphicImage value="/images/loading.gif" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="complete">
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="error">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <div class="ui-message-error">
                    <span class="ui-message-error-icon" />
                    <span class="ui-message-error-detail">
                        <h:outputText value=" Ooops! An error has occurred!" />
                    </span>
                </div>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>
    </p:ajaxStatus>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, But I think Full page load is not ajax event.